# How to change log levels details to info in Websphere?

Tags: logging, websphere

Previously I used Websphere Admin console to change the log levels details. I searched **all** places and replaced the default as **info**. After this change, my server is not starting at all. Consequently, now I don't have access to admin console to change the log levels back to info.

Is there any other way to change to the default info through some command line or through editing a file in the server?

I have modified in **Admin Console->Troubleshooting->Logs And Trace->Portal->Change log level details**

There you see two tabs Configuration and Runtime by default value for these both tab was *=info and I have changed it to *=all and the problem occurs.

Comment: can you tell where exactly in the admin console you changed the value? I mean the path? Like server -> java and process management -> etc?

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit unclear from the question as to exactly where you have done your changes. Changing the log detail levels should not mess up your server to the point where your server will no longer start.

However, to answer your question: All configurations done in the WebSphere ISC (administration console) is saved as files on the server. Changes can be done directly in the configuration file but be very careful when you do that as matters can easily get worse if editing is not done right (keep a copy of the file before you edit it).

The log detail levels are set in the `server.xml` file. This file resides in the directory `<profile_root>/config/cells/<cell_name>/nodes/<node_name>/servers/<server_name>`. In the `server.xml` file look for a line beginning with `<services xmi:type="traceservice:TraceService"`. Look for the property `startupTraceSpecification` which is where you have the full trace specification string for logs. The default is `*=info` so the property should read `startupTraceSpecification="*=info"`.

Finally, keep in mind that if the server is managed by a deployment manager any changes you do on the individual server can be overwritten by the configuration you have on the deployment manager on the next synchronization, but I assume you don't have this setup as then your server log tracing settings could be managed through the deployment managers administration console.